# How to assign to a variable a value without assignment operators

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Having the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    int f;
virtual void assign(){
    f = 7;
}
};

class Hijo: public Base
{
public:
    void assign()
    {
    //Insert solution here      
    }
};

int main(){
    Hijo h;
    h.assign();
    printf("%d",h.f);
    return 0;
}
```

In the comment "//Insert solution here", a one-line instruction should be included to assign f the value of 7 WITHOUT using assignment operators (++, +=, =, ...)

**EDIT:** There was a mistake when I copied the code. It is 7 in both places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write `Base::assign();`

Comment: Whilst I agree that this is probably the desired solution by the original quiz-setter, I don't see why  not just delete the `hijo::assign` function, and let the compiler call `Base::assign` in without having a second function in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
void assign()
{
   int seven(7); memcpy(&f, &seven, sizeof(seven));
}
```

It's obviously a completely useless exercise to do this, and not very clean either. But I think it fulfils the criteria of the task.

Comment: Sure...give me a reason to delete my answer ;)

Comment: Your answer was very different from mine tho... ;)

Comment: It should be in one line. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Now it is one line... ;)

Comment: @Oni What are you trying to do. memcpy and assignment will be broken down to the same thing by the compiler.

Comment: As I see it, this is like one of those "tricks" where someone places 6 matches on the table in some geometric pattern, and you are supposed to rearrange them to another geometric pattern (often seemingly impossible). No practical use at all.

Answer (score 0):

If it is should be `7` in BOTH cases, then this will do:

```
class Hijo: public Base
 {
  public:
   void assign()
    {
     Base::assign();
    }
 };
```

Comment: ... and then `f` ends up with `5`, not `7`.